# Attempting to set Default Value of TextBox1 within FormView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

ASP.Net using C# and WebForms

I am simply trying to populate a TextBox within a FormView with a value of approved when the page loads. The FormView's DEFAULT MODE is Edit and it will remain in Edit only. I am in need of some code and syntax that works. I have tried but I cant get the field to populate. I'm including the FormView markup and the Code Behind. I appreciate anyone that can help with this. I know it may be simple but I have had all kinds of trouble with it and I have not found anything that works.

Most of the solutions I have come across are for Inserting.

FormView1 Markup

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="test_default" DefaultMode="Edit" AllowPaging="True" >
     <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFFCC" Height="35px" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
         <br />
         id:
         <asp:Label ID="idLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
         <br />
         status:
```

Code Behind

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (FormView1.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Edit)
     {
         TextBox TextBox2 = FormView1.FindControl("TextBox2") as TextBox;
         if (TextBox2 != null)
         {
             TextBox2.Text = "approved";
         }
```

Comment: do you have a databind event for the formview? You should put the code in the databind event.

Answer (score 0):

This worked!

```
 protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (submitted_to_email != null)
        {
            _ = Context.User.Identity.Name;
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                submitted_to_email.Text = User.Identity.Name;
        }

        if (TextBox1 != null)
        {
            
                TextBox1.Text = "approved";
        }


    }
```